# How do I add custom SYNTAX to OpenLDAP?

Tags: syntax, openldap, attributes

When defining an attribute in OpenLDAP, you have to provide a SYNTAX OID so OpenLDAP knows what kind of string it can accept for that attribute.

How can I create a new SYNTAX for OpenLDAP?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You have to stick to the syntax OIDs that it already understand. You can add new attributes that obey existing syntaxes, and new `objectClasses` that use those new attributes, but that's it.